# How do I listen to when the mouse moves within the document using the Google Closure library?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to call a function when the mouse moves within the body of the document. However, the below event handler is not working.

```
goog.events.listen(document,
  'onmousemove',
  function(e) {console.log('foo');});
```

Why isn't it working? I've tried `window` instead of `document` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`onmousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmousemove) is an element property. The DOM event you are looking for is `mousemove`. See the ***[MDN DOM event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference)***.

```js
goog.events.listen(document, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log('foo');
});
```

The Closure Library provides the cross-browser event API [`goog.events.EventType`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/events/eventtype.js), which has the added benefit of preventing typos. Using this enum, your code would be written:

```js
goog.events.listen(document, goog.events.EventType.MOUSEMOVE, function(e) {
    console.log('foo');
});
```